# Replacing MySQL table fails with SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to replace an existing mySQL table with pandas, using SQLalchemy. However, it fails. I do get the following error. When appending with the same request, I succeed.

```
# This fails
tablename = 'table_name'
connection = create_engine(f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{user}:{pw}@{host}/{db}")
df.to_sql(tablename, connection, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

When using `if_exists='append'` it works.

The error message

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    wise.update_table()
  File "wise.py", line 547, in update_table
    season_table.to_sql(tablename, connection, if_exists='replace', index=False)
  File "/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2951, in to_sql
    return sql.to_sql(
  File "/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 697, in to_sql
    return pandas_sql.to_sql(
  File "/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1729, in to_sql
    table = self.prep_table(
  File "/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1628, in prep_table
    table.create()
  File "/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 835, in create
    self.pd_sql.drop_table(self.name, self.schema)
  File "/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1787, in drop_table
    self.meta.reflect(bind=self.connectable, only=[table_name], schema=schema)
  File "/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 4848, in reflect
    raise exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not reflect: requested table(s) not available in Engine(mysql+mysqlconnector://{user}:{pw}@{host}/{db}): (table_name)
```

Comment: what happens if you insert the actual values for user/pw/host/db?

Comment: I have done it :) I just did not want to expose them to the whole world